# OnGlobalLayoutListener in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to be able to expand the rows in my ListView with an animation. Therefore I need to know the height of the view that is expanding. I'm using this in the `getView()` method of my `ArrayAdapter`:

```
mDetailsView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        mDetailsView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        onClickListener.setHeight(mDetailsView.getHeight());
        mDetailsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

This works fine for the rows that are visible on screen at start, but when I scroll down, the `onGlobalLayout` method doesn't get called for the rows that weren't visible at first.

How can I get the height for those rows?

Comment: The `mDetailsView` is visible for the rows that weren't visible at first(when you scoll)?

Comment: At first I have 10 rows visible, all with `mDetailsView` `GONE`. The 11th row has `mDetailsView` `VISIBLE`, then the 22th has `VISIBLE`, etc. All other rows (12-21, 23-31, etc) has `GONE`. This is due to reusage of the `view`s using `convertView`. For all rows >= 11 `onGlobalLayout` doesn't get called.

Comment: convertView is meant for recycled views.  It's taking the same inflated view and sticking it to the bottom or top depending on where the user is scrolling.  It does this so you don't have to inflate it again.  Just call `convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE)` if you want it to be visible first thing.

Comment: I know about the use of `convertView`, that's why the rows >= 11 behave like I said they did. I'm not sure why I should set `convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`, as it's totally not what I want. If you meant `mDetailsView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`, I still don't have the height I need.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible that implementations of `ListView` don't do an entire layout so the `ViewTreeObserver` never actually sees a layout in progress.

Unless there's some specific phone case I'm not aware of, you can use the `post` method in Views to execute runnable when they're in view.

```
mDetailsView.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    onClickListener.setHeight(mDetailsView.getHeight());
    mDetailsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
});
```

**EDIT:**

<strike>I don't know how the entire `getView()` method is laid out.  The issue, if I had to guess, is the `ListView` simply isn't requesting a layout. Instead it's doing the work itself for each view to speed things up.  What you can try is this:</strike>

```
public void getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  /* 
   * set your view up
   */

  mDetailsView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        mDetailsView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        onClickListener.setHeight(mDetailsView.getHeight());
        mDetailsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
   });

   notifyDataSetInvalidated(); // Notify the ListView() and any other listeners that your views are invalid.
   return view;
}
```

*New edit*: Using `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` in usually a bad idea and especially if used in `getView()`.

To pre-measure the layout you would take it's layout params or give it new ones if they don't exist.

```
    LayoutParams params = newView.getLayoutParams();
    if (params == null) {
        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    }
    final int widthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    final int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getHeight(), MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    newView.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
```

Comment: I've tried it, this results in the `mDetailsView` to be drawn for a very short while before it being set to `GONE`. That's why I need to now the height *before* the view is drawn.

Comment: Also, when scrolling back up, the `mDetailsView`s get shown for a short time, causing my scroll y value to drop, resulting in bad scrolling behavior.

Comment: Have you tried `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` immediately after so the `ListView` is forced to layout?  The only issue here is constantly forcing a global layout is **slow** which is probably why they stopped doing in it in API 11+.  The other option is to pre-measure the layout before you return, but that would mean each layout is measured twice.  Once in the `getView()`, and once when it's added.

Comment: Immediately after what? And how would I pre-measure the layout?

Comment: I edited it.  See if it helps.  If not, I'll ponder it a bit more.  Neither solution is good at all, but the issue you're facing is the view isn't measured yet and might not be for a while.  The clean solution may require you to extend ListView and return the child's height when it is finally measured.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Unfortunately, using `notifyDataSetInvalidated`, all items disappear. For the second method, when would I retrieve the height? If `onGlobalLayout` should be called, it doesn't. Also, directly after the `measure` method, the `getHeight()` is still 0.

Comment: May try getMeasuredHeight().  getHeight() doesn't have a valid value until `layout()` is called.  With the second method, you wouldn't use a GlobalViewTreeListener.

Comment: `getMeasuredHeight()` returns 814px for `mDetailsView` instead of +- 150px. Probably due to the `parent.getHeight()` part. *Couple of tries later*: I've changed it to `final int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);` and now I get the desired height values! Thanks a lot! (Maybe you could update your answer with this line)

Comment: Ooo!  That's interesting to note. I've rarely seen UNSPECIFIED useful. Glad you got it working though.

Comment: Might I add that the code you've changed it into does not provide the desired values. All rows get the same height now. Just changing the line `final int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);` does the trick. (And removing the `heightMode` variable).

Comment: does any one have how Global layout listener work and behave?

Comment: +1 for the original answer, `post` worked for me when `onGlobalLayout` was not getting called for `ListView` Items that doesn't use recycled `convertView` and aren't `visible` on screen at first go.

Answer (score 8):

In ListView or RecyclerView instead of using `OnGlobalLayoutListener` I always use `OnPreDrawListener`. This callback is fired also for non visible  rows at start. From the official documentation:

> At this point, all views in the tree have been measured and given a frame.

Comment: imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
   new OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
     loadingFrameAnimDrawable.start();
     return true;
    }
   });

Comment: hang phone and call every time touch screen

Answer (score 2):

In ListView or RecyclerView instead of using OnGlobalLayoutListener we always use OnPreDrawListener. This callback is fired also for non visible rows at start. From the official documentation:

private void makeTextViewResizable(final TextView tv, final int maxLine, final String expandText, final boolean viewMore) {

```
    try {
        if (tv.getTag() == null) {
            tv.setTag(tv.getText());
        }
        //OnGlobalLayoutListener
        ViewTreeObserver vto = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {

                    ViewTreeObserver obs = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
                   // obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener((ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener) mActivity);
                    obs.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    if (maxLine == 0) {
                        int lineEndIndex = tv.getLayout().getLineEnd(0);
                        String text = tv.getText().subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - expandText.length() + 1) + " " + expandText;
                        tv.setText(text);
                        tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                        tv.setText(
                                addClickablePartTextViewResizable(Html.fromHtml(tv.getText().toString()), tv, expandText,
                                        viewMore), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                    } else if (maxLine > 0 && tv.getLineCount() >= maxLine) {
                        int lineEndIndex = tv.getLayout().getLineEnd(maxLine - 1);
                        String text = tv.getText().subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - expandText.length() + 1) + " " + expandText;
                        tv.setText(text);
                        tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                        tv.setText(
                                addClickablePartTextViewResizable(Html.fromHtml(tv.getText().toString()), tv, expandText,
                                        viewMore), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                    } else {
                        int lineEndIndex = tv.getLayout().getLineEnd(tv.getLayout().getLineCount() - 1);
                        String text = tv.getText().subSequence(0, lineEndIndex) + " " + expandText;
                        tv.setText(text);
                        tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                        tv.setText(
                                addClickablePartTextViewResizable(Html.fromHtml(tv.getText().toString()), tv, expandText,
                                        viewMore), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                    }


                return true;
            }


        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so looks like I had a similar issue.

For some reason, if ListView was loosing convertView in the middle, then when inflating the view anew it wasn't calling it's Global Layout Listener if it was set.

Here's the workaround I came up with:

```
public class MyViewThatIsInList extends View {
  public MyViewThatIsInList (Context context) {
      super(context);
      ensureInited();
  }

  public MyViewThatIsInList (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      this(context, attrs, 0);
  }

  public MyViewThatIsInList (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);

      TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyViewThatIsInList , 0, 0);
      //...
      ensureInited();
  }

  boolean isViewInited = false;
  private void init() {
      getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
          @Override
          public void onGlobalLayout() {
              //my custom helper method
              Utils.safeRemoveLayoutListener(getViewTreeObserver(), this);
              initLogic();
          }
      });
  }

  private void initLogic() {
    //...
    isViewInited = true;
  }

   private void ensureInited() {
      init();
      postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              if (!isViewInited) {
                  initLogic();
              }
          }
      }, 500);
  }

}
```

Comment: What is `Utils.safeRemoveLayoutListener`?

Comment: See it here: https://github.com/AAverin/android-skeleton-project/blob/master/app/src/main/java/pro/anton/averin/android/skeleton/utils/Utils.java